# Implementing Fulltext Search in attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am trying to implement fulltext search inside attachments for my new project.

Attachments include `PDF`, `EPUB`, `DOC` files.

I tried implementing this with **`gem sunspot_solr`** and **`gem sunspot_cell`** by following [this](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/indexing-rich-documents-with-rails-sunspot-solr-sunspot-cell-and-carrierwave-cookbook-style/) tutorial.

But I am facing lots of issues as the `gem` is 4 year old and it is not active.

**Is there any other `gem` or other way to implement full-text search in documents?**

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I tried this. But also faced lots of errors. And in gem itself they are telling like this (It is not considered compatible with Elasticsearch 1.x)

Answer (score 1):

I reckon thinking-sphinx would suffice your needs, http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/.

Comment: Does this support indexing attachments?. I didnt find anywhre about this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) with [elasticsearch-mapper-attachment](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments) plugin under the hood [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) is used.

There is a tutorial [here](http://rny.io/rails/elasticsearch/2013/08/05/full-text-search-for-attachments-with-rails-and-elasticsearch.html) unfortunately not updated to the last gems available for rails/elasticsearch integration but still a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:
 https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot
this lastest commit at 18 Aug. about [full text](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#full-text)

Comment: Iam asking about fulltext search inside attached pdf od doc